# XSLT 2.0 two pass process not working as expected

Tags: variables, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have two xslt transformations to apply to an xml message.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
    <ListOfBipBoxfldrlbls>
      <Batch>   
        <ListOfFolder>
          <Folder>
            <FolderNum>Fldr1</FolderNum>             
            <BoxNumber>Box1</BoxNumber>
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>
          </Folder>
          <Folder>
            <FolderNum>Fldr2</FolderNum>       
            <BoxNumber>Box1</BoxNumber>  
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>        
          </Folder>
          <Folder>
            <FolderNum>Fldr3</FolderNum>        
            <BoxNumber>Box1</BoxNumber> 
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>
          </Folder>
          <Folder>
            <FolderNum>Fldr1</FolderNum>
            <BoxNumber>Box2</BoxNumber>
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>
          </Folder>
          <Folder>
            <FolderNum>Fldr2</FolderNum>
            <BoxNumber>Box2</BoxNumber>
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>
          </Folder>
          <Folder>
            <FolderNum>Fldr3</FolderNum>
            <BoxNumber>Box2</BoxNumber>
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>
          </Folder>
          <Folder>
            <FolderNum>Fldr4</FolderNum>
            <BoxNumber>Box2</BoxNumber>
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>
          </Folder>
          </ListOfFolder>
        <ListOfBox>
          <Box>
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>
            <BoxNumber>Box1</BoxNumber>               
          </Box>
          <Box>     
            <BatchNumber>Batch</BatchNumber>
            <BoxNumber>Box2</BoxNumber>                
          </Box>
        </ListOfBox>
      </Batch>  
    </ListOfBipBoxfldrlbls>
```

Expected Output :

```
 Box1                     Box1 Fldr1       Box1 Fldr2

 Box1 Fldr3              Box2              Box2 Fldr1

 Box2 Fldr2              Box2 Fldr3        Box2 Fldr4
```

Here is my xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="phase-1-result">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="phase-1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$phase-1-result" mode="phase-2"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/" mode="phase-1">
  <ListofLabels>
    <xsl:for-each select="ListOfBipBoxfldrlbls/Batch/ListOfFolder/Folder">
      <Label>        
        <FolderNum><xsl:value-of select="FolderNum"/></FolderNum>
        <Box><xsl:value-of select="BoxNumber"/></Box>
        <Batch><xsl:value-of select="BatchNumber"/></Batch>
      </Label>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="ListOfBipBoxfldrlbls/Batch/ListOfBox/Box">
      <Label>        
        <Box><xsl:value-of select="BoxNumber"/></Box>
        <Batch><xsl:value-of select="BatchNumber"/></Batch>
      </Label>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </ListofLabels>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="$phase-1-result/ListofLabels/Label" mode="phase-2">    
    <xsl:variable name="columns" select="3" />
    <TABLE border="1">
      <xsl:for-each select="$phase-1-result/ListofLabels/Label[position() mod $columns = 1]"> 
         <TR>
           <xsl:for-each select=".|following-sibling::$phase-1-result/ListofLabels/Label[position() &lt; $columns]">
             <TD>
               <xsl:value-of select="." />
             </TD>
           </xsl:for-each> 
         </TR> 
      </xsl:for-each> 
    </TABLE> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am trying to restructure the XML in the first pass and store the result in a variable "$phase-1-result" and format in the second pass using the new structure.

The problem is xmlspy is not recognizing the Variable. it is show it as undefined variable and Error: Unexpected token "$phase-1-result/ListofLabels/Label".

Can some one help me identify the Issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be more like `{$phase-1-result}/ListofLabels/...`?

Comment: The main problem is that your XML source is incompatible with your XSLT. It won't match any nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Getting the same error if I use {$phase-1-result}/ListofLabels/.. Using xsl 2.0. if that matters.

Comment: Please add your expected output. The stylesheet is still incompatible with your source. It will not match any nodes and even if it worked it wouldn't produce any result. Check the nodes that you are matching. For example, there is no `LineNumber`, `FullName`, `TrayNumber`, `TrayNum` in the source.

Comment: @helderdarocha, Thanks for pointing it out. Fixed select="ListOfBipBoxfldrlbls/Batch/ListOfBox/Box"

Comment: @helderdarocha fixed the stylesheet.

Comment: What's your expected output? A list of tables? Add a sample of your expected output.

Comment: You can fiz one error by removing the variable from the `match` atrribute: from `match="$phase-1-result/ListofLabels/Label"` to `match="ListofLabels/Label"`. Then, inside that template (I am not sure since it depends on your expected output) try replacing the two occurrences of `$phase-1-result/ListofLabels/Label` with `node()` (assuming you are working with nodes in context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use the variable in the initial `<xsl:apply-templates select="$phase-1-result" mode="phase-2" />`.  After that you're "inside" the phase 1 result tree, and the match expressions and further selects don't need to use the variable, they just work within this new context:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="phase-1-result">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/" mode="phase-1"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <TABLE border="1">
    <xsl:apply-templates  mode="phase-2"
      select="($phase-1-result/ListOfLabels/Label)[position() mod 3 = 1]"/>
  </TABLE>
</xsl:template>

<!-- phase-1 template as before -->

<xsl:template match="Label" mode="phase-2">
  <TR>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::Label[position() lt 3]"
                         mode="columns" />
  </TR>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Label" mode="columns">
  <TD>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </TD>
</xsl:template>
```

Here I'm doing the "select every third Label" logic at the point of applying the `phase-2` template, so that template only needs to concern itself with the "me and my next two siblings" bit.

It's no different from declaring a variable containing nodes from the original input tree and then applying templates to those

```
<xsl:variable name="someNodes" select="/foo/bar | /foo/ping" />
<xsl:apply-templates select="$someNodes" />

<xsl:template match="bar">...</xsl:template>
```

The template match expressions don't care where the nodes came from, they only care what the nodes look like (is it a `bar` or a `ping`).